# JQuery/JavaScript: Why does function mess up array outside function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't get this!
The function `messup()` is supposed to alter `copy`, not `original`. What do I do wrong?

```
<head>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function messup(copy) {
            copy[0] ++;
            console.log(original);
            $('.putContentHere').html('<button class="plus">+</button>');
        }

        var original = [1, 1];
        var copy = original;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            messup(copy);

            $('html').on('click', '.plus', function() {
                messup(copy);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="putContentHere"></div>
</body>
```

How can I preserve the original while the copy is being messed up?

Comment: You have to actually *make* a copy. A simple assignment like that just makes another variable reference the same array.

Comment: How do I make a copy? I'm new here; I wasn't aware of the difference.

Comment: @user3021737 See Pointy's answer

Comment: @user3021737 - Are you new to programming? If yes, then object copying is a very important concept to know. :)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: I'm new to JavaScript. I know some PHP. No need to use the slice trick there. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to make a copy of an array is:

```
var copy = original.slice(0);
```

That makes a *shallow* copy of the array, which is fine for your purposes here.

A simple assignment:

```
var copy = original;
```

results in the new variable "copy" referencing the exact same array as "original".  Arrays are objects, and variable values *refer* to objects.

The `.slice()` method didn't exist in old versions of IE, but those are of decreasing relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Because `var copy = original;` is not copying an array.

```
What it does:
original ----------------------> Array
                                   |
                                   |
copy     --------------------------+      (The reference is copied)
=================================================================================
What you want:
original ----------------------> Array


copy     ----------------------> Array   (The Array itself is copied)
```

There are 3 (actually 4) types of copying an array: [Shallow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_copy), [Deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_copy), reference copy.

In your code you are only copying the reference. What you want to do is a shallow copy or a deep copy.

```
var copy = original.slice(); //shallow copy
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply using a reference to the original array by doing

```
var copy = original;
```

Being that your array is just a set of integers, using

```
var copy = original.slice (0);
```

will copy your array and it's contents.  So, for example:

```
var original = [1, 1, 1];
var copy = original.slice (0);

copy[1] = 2;
console.log (original); // This will print [1, 1, 1]
console.log (copy); // This will print [1, 2, 1]
```